# Error when i read excel file by C#

Tags: c#, excel

I read excel but dataGridView show data than lines excel file, So I can't write `datagridview.Rowcount()`. I use the below given code to read the excel file.

Code:

```
filePath = txtExcelFile.Text;
string[] fileSpit = filePath.Split('.');
if (filePath.Length > 1 && fileSpit[1] == "xls")
{
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'";
}
else
{
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No'";
}
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Select * from [" +comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "]", ole);
OleDbDataAdapter oledata = new OleDbDataAdapter();
oledata.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
oledata.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: Its not really clear, can you clarify that you want to do? Guessing to do a `datagridview.Rowcount()` but the blank rows are affecting the results?

Comment: Yes, I want to Rowcount of dataGridView but blank rows are incorrect the results.

Comment: How are we meant to answer this without being able to replicate your issue? There is nothing in your code that looks wrong to me. You need to provide us with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either strip out the blank lines from the data table before assigning it to the grid:

```
    private DataTable StripEmptyRows(DataTable dt)
    {
        List<int> rowIndexesToBeDeleted = new List<int>();
        int indexCount = 0;
        foreach(var row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var r = (DataRow)row;
            int emptyCount = 0;
            int itemArrayCount = r.ItemArray.Length;
            foreach(var i in r.ItemArray) if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (i.ToString())) emptyCount++;

            if(emptyCount == itemArrayCount) rowIndexesToBeDeleted.Add(indexCount);

            indexCount++;
        }

        int count = 0;
        foreach(var i in rowIndexesToBeDeleted)
        {
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i-count);
            count++;
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Or do your own row count ignoring blank rows.